# Regex not working in Sed

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm trying to run a regex over an XML file (Jira export file, to be precise) to fix an issue with some JQL-queries in it.

I'm looking for an attribute called "request", it contains a query. In that query, usernames need to be wrapped in HTML-entities for quotes ("quot;).
A username always follows the string "reporter = ', "assignee = ", or "watcher = ", except for one special case: the string currentUser() is not a username and does not need to be replaced.

```
 Original:
 <SearchRequest id="10000" name="Example" author="myusername" user="myusername" request="reporter = anotheruser and status != Closed" favCount="1"/>
 Result:
 <SearchRequest id="10000" name="Example" author="myusername" user="myusername" request="reporter = &quot;anotheruser&quot; and status != Closed" favCount="1"/>

 Search:
 (request=".*?(reporter|assignee|watcher) = )(?!currentUser)([a-z.]+)(.*?")

 Replace:
 $1&amp;$3&amp;$4
```

This has been tried and tested in SublimeText 2, and [Regex Tester 2](http://www.regextester.com/index2.html), and works correctly. As you can see, it uses a lookahead to detect the negative case for currentUser. Now, when I try to use this regex in Sed, it errors out:

```
$ sed -i '' -E 's/(request=".*?(reporter|assignee|watcher) = )(?!currentUser)([a-z.]+)(.*?")/$1&amp;$3&amp;$4/g' entities.xml
sed: 1: "s/(request=".*?(reporte ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

I'm not sure how to proceed now, as sed is new territory to me. I'm inclined to think it's the lookahead that causes this problem. Perhaps there's a simpler way to fulfil this requirement?

Comment: first of all, in sed, it's not $1, $2,... but \1, \2,...

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you meant by this: ".*?". the dot-star searches for anything for 0 to many occurences. what's with the question mark ?

Comment: @StefanosKalantzis `.*` is greedy, the question mark makes it lazy `.*?`.

Comment: As sudo_O said, it's to make the matching lazy. There are more attributes in the searchRequest. Without lazy matching, the match would run on until the closing quote of the last attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately lookaheads/behinds are not support in `sed` you should take a lot at `ssed` (super sed). Here is the [FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html) if you want more information.

Also this could be done in `perl` if you are familiar, which I am not *(I tagged with* [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) *so you should get some help).*

Using the `-P` option with `grep` verifies your match:

```
$ grep -Po '(request=".*?(reporter|assignee|watcher) = )(?!currentUser)([a-z.]+)(.*?")' <<< '<SearchRequest id="10000" name="Example" author="myusername" user="myusername" request="reporter = anotheruser and status != Closed" favCount="1"/>'
request="reporter = anotheruser and status != Closed"
```

Comment: Thanks! Using grep to verify will save me a lot of time!